# Add Power Steering Fluid instead of Dextron II

Tags: steering, power, fluid

I have a 1997 Toyota RAV4, I started adding power steering fluid, then I noticed it was not the same color, it ask for Dextron II instead. I only put maybe couple drops. Will it ruin my Power Steering, should I flush it or leave it alone? Thank you for any advise.

Comment: Are you sure the power steering fluid you were using wasn't Dextron?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of drops?

Well, if those drops were those large ones then I would empty the reservoir (a syphon bulb works well) and refill with the correct stuff. Give it a day or two then you could repeat - that way the amount left in of the incorrect stuff is only a fraction...

I don't think it is worth the hassle of completely draining pump, reservoir, pipes and steering rack....